# How to write perl format header to multiple files in a loop

Tags: perl, file, unix, format

I am developing a perl script that generates Verilog templates based on command line arguments. To that, i need to write the same header to multiple files in a loop. here is my code.

```
format MODULE_TOP=
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// RELEASE HISTORY
// VERSION DATE             AUTHOR            DESCRIPTION
// @<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$VERSION,$DATE,$AUTHOR,$DESCRIPTION
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// KEYWORDS :
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// PURPOSE  :
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
.
format MODULE=
module @<<<<<< (
$module_name

);
//signal declarations

//main body of the module

endmodule

foreach (@modules) {
  $file_name = "$_.v";
  open MODULE,'>',$file_name or die "$!";
  $FILENAME = $file_name;
  $module_name = $_;
  write MODULE;
  close MODULE; 
}
```

But the header in getting written to only the first file, The rest of the modules contain only the body. Is there any way to write the header in all the files.

Comment: where's the code for writing the header and the other material?

Comment: I've added indentation to your code. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing yourself in the future. Clear indentation is one of the best ways to help people to understand your code and if you're asking a large number of strangers to give you help, then it's surely a good idea to make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: `write()`? Are you really using [formats](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlform.pod)?

Comment: I have put the code regarding the header and body formats. @DaveCross, Is there any other way to print format other than write ?.

Comment: @vihaarivarma: No, `write()` is the correct function to use for formats. But I'd question whether formats are ever the right tool to use in 2018!

Comment: @DaveCross I'm still a perl learner. If there are any other ways to achieve my goal, I am pleased to know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not writing the header to each file because closing and re-opening the `MODULE` handle doesn't reset `$-` (`$FORMAT_LINES_LEFT` with `use English;`), the variable that tracks how many lines are left in the current page. If you reset that variable to 0 each time you reopen the file handle with a new file, it'll make the format reset to a new page. It's not clear from the documentation, but you **ALSO** have to re-`select` the file handle before doing that. Reusing file handles is tricky; one of many reasons it's good style to use autovivified ones instead of bare handles (Though that doesn't save you from having to use `select` when using formats).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

our $file;

format FOO_TOP =
Header line
-----------

.

format FOO =
Body of @<<<<<<
$file
.

for $file ("a.txt", "b.txt") {
  open FOO, ">", $file;
  my $oldfd = select FOO;
  $- = 0;
  select $oldfd;
  write FOO;
  close FOO;
}
```

The loop in the above can be written in a more modern style like so:

```
for $file ("a.txt", "b.txt") {
  open my $foo, ">", $file;
  my $oldfd = select $foo;
  $^ = "FOO_TOP";
  $~ = "FOO";
  select $oldfd;
  write $foo;
  close $foo;
}
```

Another, cleaner looking approach is to use the methods in the [IO::Handle](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html) module:

```
for $file ("a.txt", "b.txt") {
  open FOO, ">", $file;
  format_lines_left FOO 0;
  write FOO;
  close FOO;
}
```

or

```
for $file ("a.txt", "b.txt") {
  open my $foo, ">", $file;
  $foo->format_name("FOO");
  $foo->format_top_name("FOO_TOP");
  write $foo;
  close $foo;
}
```

which does the `select` wrapping for you.